# Finding the value of a constant in a Boundary Value Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, sturm-liouville

Let $t \to y(t)$ be a real-valued smooth function on any open interval containing $[0,1]$. Suppose that $y(t)$ satisfies the differential equation:

$$y''(t) + w(t)y(t) = \lambda y(t)$$

where $\lambda$ is some real constant and $w(t)$ is some function.

Suppose also that $y(t)>0$ for all $t \in [0,1]$ and that $y'(0)=y'(1)=0$.

If $\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{y'}{y}\right)^{2}\,dt = 10$, and $\int_{0}^{1}w(t)\,dt = 20$,
what is the value of $\lambda$ ?

I have had some brief exposure to Sturm-Liouville Theory, but not enough to be able to handle such problems. How do we go about this one?

Comment: Hint: divide the equation by $y(t)$ (possible due to the positivity condition), then integrate from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: Yeah, thats all I had to do. Was blind to it initially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y''(t) + w(t)y(t) = \lambda y(t)$$
Since $y(t) \ne 0$:
$$\dfrac {y''(t)}{y} + w(t) = \lambda $$
$$\left (\dfrac {y'(t)}{y}\right)'+\dfrac {y'^2}{y^2} + w(t) = \lambda $$
Integrate:
$$\int_0^1\left (\dfrac {y'(t)}{y}\right)'dt+\int_0^1 \dfrac {y'^2}{y^2}dt + \int_0^1 w(t)dt = \lambda \int_0^1 dt $$
$$\lambda=\int_0^1\left (\dfrac {y'}{y}\right)'dt +30 $$
$$\lambda=\dfrac {y'}{y}\Bigg\rvert_0^1 +30 $$
Note that $y(0) \ne 0$ and $y(1) \ne 0$ (since suppose also that $y(t)>0$ for all $t \in [0,1])$ and $y'(0)=y'(1)=0$:
$$\lambda=30$$

Comment: Can't believe the solution was just in front of me. The room was just too dark for me to spot it. Thanks!!

Comment: You're welcome @krishna2016